# how to test on variables in sql server triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, if-statement

i need to test if a variable exists in a certain list so i use

```
if @someVar in ('value1','value2','value3',)
   begin

   end
```

but this doesn't work, the body of the if statement is never executed even if @someVar is equals to a value.

could you help please, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does work there must be some other problem in your code.

```
declare @someVar varchar(50) = 'value1'

if @someVar in ('value1','value2','value3')
   begin
   print 'yes'
   end
```

Returns `yes`

Are you assigning a value to `@someVar`? Have you forgotten to give it a length in the variable declaration so it is being silently truncated to 1 character?

Comment: @joe - Case sensitivity depends on the collation of your database. You'll need to post more code.

Comment: perhaps you need to share the whole triggers so we can see what is really going on.

Comment: Martin, Thanks a lot.. it was truncated. i tested the trigger manually..insert and with some print statements i figure out it was truncated to 1 Char as you said, i added a length to my varcha and it works just fine THANKS